# Конкретное разрешение для media

Tags: css, responsive

Как в правиле @media указывать конкретное разрешение,а не только ширину окна? Хочу адаптировать для отдельных девайсов,но не могу понять как

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве случаев подходит такие варианты (от Bootstrap'a):

```
// Самые маленькие устройства (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Маленькие устройства (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Средние устройства (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Большие устройства (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }
```

Или еще такой вариант (если нужен какой то один конкретный он подойдет больше):

```
// Самые маленькие устройства (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Маленькие устройства (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Средние устройства (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Большие устройства (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

// Самые большие устройства (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

В `head` добавьте:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

На самом деле вариантов огромное количество, зависит от устройства,
Можете найти его [здесь](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: Спасибо огромное. то что нужно